# Surfaceview surfaceCreated() function is not called

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-camera, surfaceview

I have created  a Surfaceview to show my camera preview. I am setting surface view width and height at run time using onMeasure() function.

**If i comment "setLayoutParams(lp)" from my onMeasure() function then my surface view is getting created and camera preview is show.** But it is not proper as surface width and height is not able to hold the aspect ratio of camera preview. Due to that preview looks bit stretched. To avoid the stretched i am calculating aspect ratio and based on the aspect ratio i am setting width and height of surfaceview. So that it can show the correct camera preview.

**For the very first time  surfaceCreated function is not called**. As i have implemented the camera switch function so when i switch the camera then surfaceCreated function is called and after that it works fine.

***Could you please let me know how "setLayoutParams(lp)" is affecting Surfaceview creation?***

Note : -  I am adding camera preview object to FrameLayout. Which is part of my fragment layout.

Below is my CameraPreview class.

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera        mCamera;
Double  aspectRatio;
Context context;


public CameraPreview(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Log.d(TAG, " CameraPreview constructor");
    this.context = context;
    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.face_capture_layout_border));
}

/**
 * Extract supported preview and flash modes from the camera.
 *
 * @param camera
 */
public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    mCamera = camera;
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size pictureSize = getLargestPictureSize(params);
    params.setPictureSize(pictureSize.width, pictureSize.height);
    aspectRatio = new Double((float) pictureSize.width / pictureSize.height);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
    requestLayout();
}

private Camera.Size getLargestPictureSize(Camera.Parameters params) {
    Camera.Size bestSize = null;
    List<Camera.Size> sizeList = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    bestSize = sizeList.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < sizeList.size(); i++) {
        if ((sizeList.get(i).width * sizeList.get(i).height) >
                (bestSize.width * bestSize.height)) {
            bestSize = sizeList.get(i);
        }
    }
    return bestSize;
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, " Surface created");
    Surface surface = getHolder().getSurface();
    Log.d(TAG, "Surface is in created valid =>" + surface.isValid());
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    Log.d(TAG, " Surface destroyed");
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
}

void startCameraPreview() {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here

    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    Log.d(TAG, " Surface changed");
    startCameraPreview();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    Log.d(TAG, "On measure");
    //Parent frame size
    View parent = (View) getParent();
    int width = parent.getWidth();
    int height = parent.getHeight();
    int surfaceViewWidth = (int) (height / aspectRatio);
    int surfaceViewHeight = (int) (height);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(surfaceViewWidth, surfaceViewHeight);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    setLayoutParams(lp);
   super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

}